# Matlab - how to convert date format in example provided

Tags: matlab

In my code below I am unable to convert the date format in column 1 from dd/MM/yyyy to MM-dd-yyyy. How do I configure it correctly to stop seeing this error??

```
>> T = readtable("IGEv3.xlsx");
>> tday=T{2:end, 1};
>> tday=datestr(datenum(tday, 'dd-MM-yyyy'), 'MM-dd-yyyy')
Error using datetime/datenum
Too many input arguments.
```

[image: Table extract]

Comment: What does `tday=T{2:end, 1}` return? Can you please display that output? This will help troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like your `Date` column contains `datetime` values instead of strings or datenum doubles. (Strings or cellstrs show up with quotes in table display output. And the error message "Error using datetime/datenum" means that you're calling `datenum()` on a `datetime` input.)

`datetime` values support datestr calls directly. You can probably just do this:

```matlab
tday=datestr(T{2:end,1}, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
```

And personally, I find it more readable when you reference variables by name instead of index:

```matlab
tday = datestr(T.Date(2:end), 'mm-dd-yyyy')
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. I tried your answers but whilst the reformated the date the month for every row changed to 00. For example '00-02-2007' why might this be?

Comment: That's because it should be a lower case "mm" for month. Upper case "MM" is minutes.  :) I've updated my answer to reflect this.